# C Error between define and char pointer declaration

Tags: c, linux, pointers, sdl, declare

I'm trying to learn a simple way to create a controllable window in Linux, and research led me to use SDL. I was on the second part of http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL where I load an image on the screen. I copied their code and created custom define values. This is my code:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#define SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED 0
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600
#define SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN 1

SDL_Window* gWindow;
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface;
SDL_Surface* gHelloWorld;

int init(){
int success = 1;
if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
{
    printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    success = 0;
}
else
{
    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    if( gWindow == NULL )
    {
    printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    success = 0;
    }
    else
    {
    gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow );
    }
}
return success;
}

int loadMedia(){
int success = 1;
gHelloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP( "/circuit.png" );
if( gHelloWorld == NULL )
{
    printf( "Unable to load image! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    success = 0;
}
return success;
}

void close()
{
SDL_FreeSurface( gHelloWorld );
gHelloWorld = NULL;
SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
gWindow = NULL;
  SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]){
  init();
  loadMedia();
  close();
  return 0;
}
```

When compiling it, even with the "-Wall" and "-Wextra" compiler flags turned on and the "-lSDL" parameter added, the first error I get is:

```
program.c:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
```

I then proceeded to add equals to the defines thinking I did something stupid, so my first few lines are now this:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#define SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED=0
#define SCREEN_WIDTH=800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT=600
#define SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN=1
```

When attempting to compile again, I see:

```
warning: missing whitespace after the macro name
```

and that's regarding each equals sign I put in. and I also see the same error as above.

It didn't complain about SDL.h not being found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You had the `#define`s right the first time.  My guess is that it doesn't know about the type `SDL_Window`, although I'm not sure why since I think it should be included in the SDL header.

Comment: It sounds as though you have an `SDL/SDL.h` header that is empty or otherwise valid but not relevant in a directory where the compiler is looking, and it is not finding the 'official' version.  Since you're using `-Wall`, you should add `-H` too — that will tell you which file is included for `SDL/SDL.h`.  And, the chances are good that knowing which file is included will show what's going wrong.  Fundamentally, in the first version, the `SDL_Window` type is not known — so the `SDL/SDL.h` header is presumably not doing its job.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `=` in your `#define`. Your program is not recognizing `SDL_Window` because it hasn't been declared yet. I suspect you are trying to compile a SDL 2 code with a 1.2 header.